# Store hidden sync identifier in android raw contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'd like to create an app which syncs contacts from a given server. To identify those contacts, I'd like to store a identifier in the android contact in a hidden field.

I've found the field [SYNC1](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.BaseSyncColumns.html#SYNC1) which seems to appropriate for that, but I've no idea how to use this field correctly.

I tried setting it in the following way:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
        new ArrayList<>();

int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC1, "myInternalId")
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Test User")
        .build());

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

The issue is now, that the batch insert runs through, but the field isn't set in the contact, because it is empty when I try to read it afterwards:

```
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String sync1 = null;
        int sync1Index = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC1);
        if (sync1Index >= 0) {
            sync1 = cur.getString(sync1Index);
        }

        System.out.println("Contact id=" + id + " name=" + name + " sync1=" + sync1);
    }
}

cur.close();
```

If I want to set it in the raw contact, so in the second batch, I get an exception.

Comment: is empty or sync1Index < 0? ... passing null as second parameter of query is not a good idea ... better pass the columns which you wana get ... also you are getting all contacts with your query not only the one from you account type

Comment: syncIndex is < 0, so the result does not contain this column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you insert the value seems correct, but the method that reads the value isn't.

You can't query `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` and get fields from the `RawContacts` table.

To read back your value, try this:

```
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.SYNC1 }
String selection = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = '" + accountType + "' AND " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = '" + accountName + "'";
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    Long rawId = cur.getLong(0);
    Long contactId = cur.getLong(1);
    String sync1 = cur.getString(2);

    System.out.println("Contact id=" + contactId + " raw-id=" + rawId + " sync1=" + sync1);
}

cur.close();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I've improved the query so that it is safe for SQL injection, by using the parameter `selectionArgs` and the placeholder `?` in the selection.